# Android: multiple-user how to change system locale/ language per single User

Tags: android, locale, android-configchanges, android-multiple-users

I'm working on the AOSP with multiple-user.
I need to change the default system language (or locale) to single user, all my attempts change the entire system language for all users.

I use the ActivityManagerNative class, updateConfiguration(myConfiguration)

is it possible? if so, how :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to do this with the settings on my Android 4.4.4 tablet (not AOSP, but Nexus 7 (2013)) and it gave me a warning that it would change the locale for all users.  :(

I think this is not possible, neither programmatically, or physically.